# Can I use text from a listitem later on?

Tags: android, flutter, text

So my question probably didn't sum up what I'm trying to do very well. Inside the Stack -> Padding, currently I have text that is named '$zoneName'. I'm trying to get it so that the imageurl that's fed into Zone (zero_one, zero_two) is displayed, so that it matches the correlating index. Right now it's written a little 'wonky' because I was trying a few different things, but I think the structure to understand what I'm asking is there.

```
import 'package:arknights_random_app/pages/griditemmap.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:arknights_random_app/pages/maps.dart';

class MapSelection extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapSelectionState createState() => _MapSelectionState();
}

class _MapSelectionState extends State<MapSelection> {
  List<Zone> itemZoneList;
  List<Zone> selectedZoneList;

  var zoneName = '$imageurl';
  Card card;

  @override
  void initState() {
    loadList();
    super.initState();
  }

  loadList() {
    itemZoneList = List();
    selectedZoneList = List();
    itemZoneList.add(Zone(zero_one, 1));
    itemZoneList.add(Zone(zero_two, 2));
    itemZoneList.add(Zone(zero_three, 3));
    itemZoneList.add(Zone(zero_four, 4));
    itemZoneList.add(Zone(zero_five, 5));
    itemZoneList.add(Zone(zero_six, 6));
    itemZoneList.add(Zone(zero_seven, 7));
    itemZoneList.add(Zone(zero_eight, 8));
    itemZoneList.add(Zone(zero_nine, 9));
    itemZoneList.add(Zone(zero_ten, 10));
    itemZoneList.add(Zone(zero_eleven, 11));

//  selectedMapList.addAll(itemMapList);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print(selectedZoneList);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
      appBar: getAppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 5, 15, 5),
        child: GridView.builder(
            itemCount: itemZoneList.length,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                childAspectRatio: 1.72,
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                mainAxisSpacing: 20),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  ),
                  semanticContainer: true,
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
//                color: _calculateColor(index),
                  elevation: 10.0,
                  child: Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        GridItemMap(
                            map: itemZoneList[index],
                            isSelected: (bool value) {
                              setState(() {
                                if (value) {
                                  selectedZoneList.add(itemZoneList[index]);
                                  print("$index : $value");
                                } else {
                                  selectedZoneList.remove(itemZoneList[index]);
                                }
                              });
                            },
                            key: Key(itemZoneList[index].rank.toString())),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 4),
                          child: Text('$zoneName',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                        ),

                      ]));
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

//  Color _calculateColor(int index) {
//    if (index <= 18) {
//      return Colors.orange[800];
//    } else if (index >= 19 && index <= 63) {
//      return Colors.amber[600];
//    } else if (index >= 64 && index <= 96) {
//      return Colors.purple[100];
//    } else if (index >= 97 && index <= 113) {
//      return Colors.lightBlueAccent[400];
//    } else if (index >= 114 && index <= 118) {
//      return Colors.limeAccent;
//    }
//    //etc

  //default case, shouldn't reach here
//    return Colors.grey;
//  }

  getAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850],
        elevation: 0.0,
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_left),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home')),
        title: Text("Map Selection"));
  }
}

class Zone {
  String imageUrl;
  int rank;

  Zone(this.imageUrl, this.rank);
}
```